# SP 2010 to SP 2013 Migration - Mounting issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

The Mounting process is showing percentage completed 0.27% for more than 10 hrs. is this normal or error.

> we are trying to Mount ~ 350 GB content DB
>
> We noticed an error which is marked as critical in both **sharepoint** as
>   well as **database server** output

```
"Cannot alter the role 'SPDataAccess', because it doesn't exist or you do not have permission. Cannot grant, deny or revoke permissions to sa,dbo,entity owner, information_Schema,sys or yourself"

Please provide your inputs

    SP 2010 to SP 2013 Migration - Mounting issue

    0.27% : SPContentDatabase Name=TWIN***_GR**Di****n_C***ent.



100% Mounting completed
```

Comment: The Mounting process is showing percentage completed 0.27% for more than 3 days. is this normal or error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a SQL permissions issue. You may need to ensure your farm account has DB_Owner mapping to the SQL database prior to mounting it. If the command is still running it might be best to start from scratch by deleting the SQL database and re-copying/restoring it from the SP2010 version.

PS: it's definitely not recommended in a production environment, but it might be easier to give the farm account Sysadm to the SQL instance, at least while you attempt to Mount the DB to SP2013.